# Difference between two rows divided by the previous row

Tags: r

I have been able to find the difference between two consecutive rows for every column but now I need to divide this by the previous row.

```
Date    FXDL.AED.USD    FXDL.ALL.USD
03/01/2005  3.6726  92.1
04/01/2005  3.6726  92.1
05/01/2005  3.6725  94.5
06/01/2005  3.6726  95.1
07/01/2005  3.6725  95.3
```

For example, the difference between (row 2 - row 1)/row 1 then (row 3 - row 2)/row 2 etc. for each column.

I have used `diff_fxdl_weekdays <- sapply(fxdl_weekdays[,sapply(fxdl_weekdays, is.numeric)], diff)`to find the difference and then I attempted to divide this by `-nrow` but this didn't work.

Comment: Does your actual dataframe have only the three columns listed (one date, two numeric)?  Is it only the numeric columns you want to calculate for, or the dates as well? (If the latter, do you want values in # of days, or...?) How do you want your final output to look (e.g., tack on values as new columns in existing df, new vector for values for each column, etc)?

Answer (score 4):

One idea is by using `dplyr` package and `lag` function,

```
library(dplyr)

#define the function
fun1 <- function(x){ (x - lag(x))/lag(x)}

mutate_if(df, is.numeric, fun1)
#        Date  FXDL.AED.USD FXDL.ALL.USD
#1 03/01/2005            NA           NA
#2 04/01/2005  0.000000e+00  0.000000000
#3 05/01/2005 -2.722867e-05  0.026058632
#4 06/01/2005  2.722941e-05  0.006349206
#5 07/01/2005 -2.722867e-05  0.002103049
```

If you also want to keep the original columns, then simply,

```
mutate_if(df, is.numeric, funs('diff' = fun1))
#        Date FXDL.AED.USD FXDL.ALL.USD FXDL.AED.USD_diff FXDL.ALL.USD_diff
#1 03/01/2005       3.6726         92.1                NA                NA
#2 04/01/2005       3.6726         92.1      0.000000e+00       0.000000000
#3 05/01/2005       3.6725         94.5     -2.722867e-05       0.026058632
#4 06/01/2005       3.6726         95.1      2.722941e-05       0.006349206
#5 07/01/2005       3.6725         95.3     -2.722867e-05       0.002103049
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a function:

```
f <- function(x) c(NA,(tail(x,-1) - head(x,-1))/head(x,-1))
```

Apply it to the numeric columns:

```
sapply(d[,sapply(d, is.numeric)], f)
```

And if you want to add it to the dataframe:

```
# replace the numeric columns with the new ones:
d[, sapply(d, is.numeric)] <- sapply(d[,sapply(d, is.numeric)], f)
# add new colums to the dataframe:
d[, paste0(names(d)[sapply(d, is.numeric)],'_diff')] <- sapply(d[,sapply(d, is.numeric)], f)
```

The result of the latter:

```
> d
        Date FXDL.AED.USD FXDL.ALL.USD FXDL.AED.USD_diff FXDL.ALL.USD_diff
1 2005-01-03       3.6726         92.1                NA                NA
2 2005-01-04       3.6726         92.1      0.000000e+00       0.000000000
3 2005-01-05       3.6725         94.5     -2.722867e-05       0.026058632
4 2005-01-06       3.6726         95.1      2.722941e-05       0.006349206
5 2005-01-07       3.6725         95.3     -2.722867e-05       0.002103049
```